# Jquery IE8 prev not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The following code snippet works in FF but not on IE8. Prev is returning correct element but not as an object that supports val(). Hence, I can not run .val() on it.

```
  <input type="hidden" name="data[De][1]" value="1" id="De1" />
   <td class="dr_name">document1</td>
   <td class="remove_dr" colspan="2" align="left">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a></td>

<script>
$(".remove_dr").live('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).prev().prev().val();
  alert(value);
}
</script>
```

Any help or a better piece of code is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a `<table>`? If you use a `form` things *might* be less tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Things:

1. You can't have an `<input>` beside a `<td>`
2. If you could (and you can't!), use siblings:

   `var value = $(this).parent().siblings("input:hidden").val();`

You need to relocate that hidden input to be at a valid location.

Comment: Firefox does tend to be more tolerant of invalid markup... which can be both good and bad.

Comment: Thanks. The hidden field had to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing paren on your call to live():

```
$(".remove_dr").live('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).prev().prev().val();
  alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one more `prev` call assuming they are all at the same level... but they arent even siblings. the input is not inside the same `td` as the `a` so its not going to work. furthermore that input needs to be within a `td` yu cant jsut have it randaomly in a table structure.

Answer (score 0):

While using live events I've observed that there is a difference for Firefox and IE. That is why I use this function to get the same event target throughout all browsers:

```
getEventTarget = function(e){
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) targ = targ.parentNode; 
    return targ;
}
```

so inside

```
$(".remove_dr").live('click', function(e) {
  eventTarget = getEventTarget(e);
  // e.preventDefault(); you can return false instead
  var value = $(eventTarget).prev().prev().val();
  alert(value);
  return false;
});
```

hope that this is what your looking for

Answer (score 0):

I found a case where prev() wasn't working as expected on IE8.  I find that using prevAll("selector:eq(0)") did work as a substitute for prev("selector").